# Why getting this error when I'm creating new app in my django project Using command "python manage.py startapp authsss"

Tags: django

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named auth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Import Error there is No module name auth which you imported somewhere in you project.

in your trace-back it is mentioned at last :

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubunt/Desktop/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named auth
```

Last line :

ImportError: No module named auth

Comment: if another trackback cursors let me know

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got this error when i'm creating a custom login page in django project.. suppose you created a app that call auth but due some reason you deleted this app from your project but not uninstall ('auth',)from project setting.py.

so if in future you get error like this then it is one of among problem that remove 'auth', also from project setting.py